# Typescript and interface arrays undefined and not assignable

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm having trouble getting the syntax right for the Typescript React Props.
I have an array of people each of which may have 0 - many cars. I have a people container that will contain all people, each person will have a car container that may contain cars, and car components that will be inside the car container.

I need to have the container for cars anyways because I will add edit buttons which will add cars to the person.

I'll add my code from top down:

PersonSlice:

```
export interface PersonState {
  id?: number;
  firstname?: string;
  lastname?: string;
  email?: string;
  created_at?: any;
  updated_at?: any;
  cars?: [];
}
```

People.tsx:

```
function People() {
  const people = useAppSelector(selectPerson);   //person is of type interface PersonState[]
  let contents;
    contents = <><div className="personcontainer">
      {people && people.length > 0 && people.map(person => {
        return <div key={person.id}>
          <Person
           dispatch={dispatch} 
           person={person}
           toggleEditForm={() => toggleEditForm(person.id)}
           personToEdit={personToEdit}
           submitEdit={submitEdit}
           />
          </div>
      })}
      </div></>
  });
}
```

This is where I start to have problems -

Person.tsx:

```
interface PersonProps {
  dispatch: Dispatch<any>;
  person: PersonState;
  toggleEditForm: () => void;
  submitEdit: any;
  personToEdit: number;
}

function Person(props: PersonProps) {
  return (
    <div className="person">
      <Cars cars={props.person.cars}/>  //cars error: type [] | undefined not assignable to car[]
    </div>
  );
}
```

cars.tsx:

```
import {car, Car} from './car';
interface cars {
    cars: car[];
}
function Cars (props: cars) {
    return (
        <div className="carcontainer">
            <h2>cars container</h2>
            {props.cars && props.cars.map((carobj: car) => {
                <Car car={carobj} key={}/>   //car error: Type '{ car: car; key: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & car'.
            })}
            </div>
    )
}
export default Cars;
```

and finally car.tsx:

```
export interface car {
    year: number,
    make:string,
    model: string,
    price: number,
    person_id: number,
}
export function Car (props: car) {
    return (
        <div className="carcontainer">
            <h3>
                {props.year} {props.make} {props.model} {props.price}
                </h3>
            </div>
    )
}
```

So I have two errors, one in person.tsx and one in cars.tsx which I added as comments in the code.

I've read like a dozen questions on this but I'm still super confused. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Why are all properties in your `interface PersonState` optional? That's part of the problem.

Comment: I will be sending updates to my api which may not contain all fields

Comment: In which case your `interface PersonState` should be renamed to `interface PersonResponseDto` and you should have a separate `class PersonState` for representing People in your Redux state store: DTOs should not be used directly for application state: `class` types are better because you can have ctor logic (which makes guarantees about validity), methods and properties - you can't do that with deserialized JSON objects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it kinda went over my head, I'm mostly just following a tutorial and is the first time I'm working with my own api. Could you recommend a resource to learn more about DTO and ctor?

Comment: `contents = <><div className="personcontainer">` - is the empty `<>` at the start unintentional?

Comment: Oops, It was a solution I tried for something else, I think returning react fragments or something.

Comment: The advice isn't TypeScript-specific: "DTOs" means "data transfer object": it's a general pattern (in many languages and systems) where data is passed around in a "POCO" object comprised of _only_ properties/fields, without any methods (but can have (invariant) validation logic in their ctors); and "ctor" is a general abbreviation for `constructor`. In TypeScript/JSON specifically: when you use `JSON.parse` or `{}` then you're using POJO objects, not `class` objects, which means you can only use `interface` types containing only trivial properties (no methods, functions, ctors, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix to both issues is in `cars.tsx`.

```
import {car, Car} from './car';
interface cars {
    cars?: car[]; // make this optional since the data from PeopleState is optional
}
function Cars (props: cars) {
    return (
        <div className="carcontainer">
            <h2>cars container</h2>
            {props.cars && props.cars.map((carobj: car) => {
                <Car {...carobj} key={}/>   // spread carobj into the component
            })}
            </div>
    )
}
export default Cars;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Cars cars={props.person.cars}/>  //cars error: type [] | undefined not assignable to car[]
```

This isn’t really an error.  You specifically wrote:

```
  cars?: [];
```

This means, “I might not know where or not the person has any cars.”  If you don’t, obviously you cannot render the list of cars.

Maybe you really might not know, in which case, your code should be something like:

```
 { props.person.cars? 
    <Cars cars={props.person.cars}/> 
    : <span>I do not know if he has cars</span> }
```

Or, you really know about the cars, but you might know that there are no cars, in which case you should say so:

```
  cars: [];
```

In the second issue, you need to actually give it a key:

```
 {props.cars && props.cars.map((carobj: car, idx) =>
            <Car car={carobj} key={idx}/>   )}
```

Comment: Would you agree that people should default to `readonly T[]` for array-types as well? It works well in immutable contexts (like Redux/React) because only `readonly T[]` supports variance.